# Creating a matrix and plotting its columns with legends

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have 2 questions:

Question 1:

```
val = Table[10 i + j, {i, 4}, {j, 3}]
```

> `{{11, 12, 13}, {21, 22, 23}, {31, 32, 33}, {41, 42, 43}}`

```
enpva = Table[4 x + 3, {x, 2, 4}]
```

> `{11, 15, 19}`

I create `xpol` as a matrix of zeros with the same dimensions as `val`.

Then I replace parts of `xpol` where for each column of `val`, if the i-th element, say of `val[[All,1]]` is equal to the i-th element of `enpva`, the i-th element of the first column of `xpol` equals 2; otherwise 1. The command in Matlab is

```
if val(i, j) == enpva(i), xpol(i, j) = 2; else xpol(i, j) = 1;
```

So `xpol` would be a matrix of 1's and 2's. I then want to take the first differences for each column of `xpol` (that is, the 2nd-1st element, 3rd-2nd element, 4th-3rd and so on). So `xpol` at the end would have the one less row but the same number of columns and would have 1's and 0's.

My real version is a larger dimensional matrix for `val` and `enpva`, but I just cannot create this matrix `xpol`. I have tried the command `If` in Mathematica, but I could not.

Question 2:

I want to make a `ListLinePlot` for each column of `val` with legends. I have tried

```
val1 = 
  Legended[
    ListLinePlot[Table[val[[All, 1]][[i]], {i, 1, 3}], 
      PlotStyle -> Red, 
      AxesLabel -> 
       {"Coal Price", "Value"}],
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(0\)]\)->Red"]
```

Similarly,

```
val3 = 
  Legended[
    ListLinePlot[Table[val[[All, 3]][[i]], {i, 1, 3}], 
      PlotStyle -> Red, 
      AxesLabel -> 
        {"Coal Price", "Value"}],
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(0\)]\)->Black"]
```

Then I tried

```
label = 
  LineLegend[
    {Red, Black}, 
    {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(0\)]\)", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(T\)]\)"}]
```

and I wanted to combine all of them with

```
Show [val1, val3, label]
```

This did not work. Besides, it's a very primitive way of doing this. All I want to do is, do the `ListLinePlot` of `val1` and `val3` with colored legends showing the curves `val1` and `val3`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please try to use [editing help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to make this question tidy.

Comment: You have asked ten questions on this site so far: each one had to be formatted by a kind soul to make it readable. It is time that you learn how to copy/paste readable code, and how to format your own questions. In addition to the tutorial Kuba mentioned, look at: [How to copy code from Mathematica](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951); and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). It is in your best interest to present a good question: more people will be interested, and you will receive prompter answers.

Comment: Thank you. I have gone over the post. I will make sure that I format better the next time.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an answer to your list manipulation question.

```
val = Table[10 i + j, {i, 4}, {j, 3}];
valCol = Transpose[val];
enpva = Table[4 x + 3, {x, 2, 4}];

xpol =
  MapThread[
    With[{e = #2}, Map[Function[v, Boole[v == e] + 1], #1]] &,
    {valCol, enpva}]
```

> `{{2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}`

```
Differences /@ xpol
```

> `{{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}`

Here is an answer to your plot legending question.

```
ListLinePlot[valCol,
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Black},
  AxesLabel -> {"Coal Price", "Value"},
  PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[Automatic, {"val1", "val2", "val3"}]]
```

[image: plot]